# Merge two array of objects based on same key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        like_id: 1, 
        likes: 1,
        post_id: 1,
        type: "feed_post_likes",
        _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329"
    }, 
    {
        post_id: 1,
        created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z",
        post_message: "Happy",
        post_pic: "",
        post_type: "post"
    }
]
```

I need to merge these array based on post_id and get this:

```
[
    {
        like_id: 1,
        likes: 1,
        post_id: 1,
        type: "feed_post_likes",
        _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329",
        created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z",
        post_message: "Happy",
        post_pic: "",
        post_type: "post"
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Hi Ayushi, if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. And if you have the ability to upvote then upvoting answers that were useful to you is also a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following using array reduce method,

```js
arr = [
    {
        like_id: 1, 
        likes: 1,
        post_id: 1,
        type: "feed_post_likes",
        _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329"
    }, 
    {
        post_id: 1,
        created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z",
        post_message: "Happy",
        post_pic: "",
        post_type: "post"
    }
];

ret = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const idx = prev.findIndex(item => item.post_id === curr.post_id);    
  if(idx > -1) {
    prev[idx] = {...prev[idx], ...curr};
  } else {
    prev.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I propose:

```js
const arrayTest = [
{like_id: 1, likes: 1, post_id: 1, type: "feed_post_likes", _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329"},
{post_id: 1, created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z", post_message: "Happy", post_pic: "", post_type: "post"}
]

const result = arrayTest.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const hasIdAlready = acc.some(e => e.post_id === curr.post_id);
    if (hasIdAlready) {
        return acc
    }
    
    const foundMatchingElems = arrayTest.filter(e => e.post_id === curr.post_id)
    
        const mergedObjects = foundMatchingElems.reduce((obj, e) => ({...obj, ...e}), {})
        return [...acc, mergedObjects]
    
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to merge objects with the same `post_id` and then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of the merged objects.

```js
const items = [
  { like_id: 1, likes: 1, post_id: 1, type: 'feed_post_likes', _id: 'b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329' },
  { post_id: 1, created_date: '2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z', post_message: 'Happy', post_pic: '', post_type: 'post' }
]

const result = items.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  ...acc,
  [item.post_id]: {
    ...acc[item.post_id] || {},
    ...item
  }
}), {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array of objects storing every `post_id` that has already been processed and for those that haven't yet been processed you can use `array.filter()` to return an array of objects that have a given `post_id` and then `array.reduce()` to merge all the objects into one using `Object.assign()`:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        like_id: 1, 
        likes: 1,
        post_id: 1,
        type: "feed_post_likes",
        _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329"
    }, 
    {
        post_id: 1,
        created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z",
        post_message: "Happy",
        post_pic: "",
        post_type: "post"
    }
];

let processed = [];
let result = [];

for(obj in arr) {
  if(processed.indexOf(arr[obj].post_id) < 0) {
    processed.push(arr[obj].post_id);
    result.push(arr.filter(item => item.post_id == arr[obj].post_id)
                .reduce((acc, currVal) => Object.assign(acc, currVal), {}));
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map), iterating the input using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and merging objects with the same `post.id` using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). The result is the [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator of the `Map` converted to an array.

```js
const input = [{ like_id: 1, likes: 1, post_id: 1, type: "feed_post_likes", _id: "b51771798ed01795cb8a17b028000329" }, { post_id: 1, created_date: "2021-03-10T10:54:35.264Z", post_message: "Happy", post_pic: "", post_type: "post" }];

const grouped = new Map(input.map(like => [like.post_id, {}]));
for (let like of input) {
  Object.assign(grouped.get(like.post_id), like);
}
const result = [...grouped.values()];

console.log(result)
```